# Why isn't the final default argument being used in this function call?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
void loopAndCompress(int value, T&& t = int())
{
}
int main()
{
    loopAndCompress(1);
}
```

> Could not deduce template argument for T

Why isn't it deducing the type? Do default arguments not work for templates types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the types of default arguments are not used in deducing type parameters; this is item #4 under "Non-deduced contexts" at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction.

However, you can specify a default template argument to be used if type deduction fails:

```
template <typename T = int>
void loopAndCompress(int value, T&& t = int())
{
}
```

(Hat-tip to Raymond Chen for pointing this out.)

Comment: Or write `template<typename T = int>`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Good call — will update, thanks!

Comment: Given that `T` may not be `int`, you probably also want `T && t = T()`.

Comment: `T&& t = std::decay_t<T>()` in case somebody does `loopAndCompress<int const&>(0)`. (If somebody does `loopAndCompress<int&>(0)`, you're doomed, since an lvalue reference can't bind to a prvalue.)